# How to display link and paragraph, when hover on image which is in "a" tag?

Tags: html, css

```
<td width="209" height="94"><a href="../pages/suppliers.php"><img id="img1" src="../images/Suppliers.png" alt="supplier" width="89" height="90"    align="middle"/></a></td>

<td id="tdHome" height="66">
  <p id="p1"><a href="suppliers.php">New Supplier</a></p>
    <p>Enter a new supplier to buy from</p></td>

#p1 {
display: none;
}

#img1:hover + #p1 {
display: block!important;
}
```

Can anyone please help me to find the problem which stops displaying paragraph, when hover on the image.

Code changed to have a same parent for img and p tags.

```
  <td width="209" rowspan="3"><p><a href="../pages/suppliers.php"><img id="img1" src="../images/Suppliers.png" alt="supplier" width="89" height="90" align="middle"/></a>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p id="p1"><a href="suppliers.php">New Supplier</a></p>
  <p>Enter a new supplier to buy from</p>
  <p><a href="suppliers.php">Supplier List</a></p>
  <p>View/update or delete suppliers</p></td>
```

Comment: Sorry, you can't as there is no parent element selector in css.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Thank you for the prompt response. As I am new to coding, can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: You need to restructure your html so that img and #p1 html resides within same parent.

Comment: I put them in same parent td tag. Is that ok? Still having the same issue.

Comment: post a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't, as it is not allowed me to add a new question, saying "You have reached your question limit". I edited the code above. Thanks.

Comment: Still you're not having parent element for both elements.

Comment: Can you please guide me to do that?Highly appreciated.

Comment: Keep your #p1 and img element in `a` tag together.